# Convert fbk (Firebird) to CSV

Tags: firebird

I have a .fbk file and I want to convert it into Excel or csv file.
I used https://www.rebasedata.com/convert-fbk-to-csv-online , but I have to pay to get all data.

Does enyone know any free software or another way to covert it?

Comment: Note that CSV as termed in Microsoft Excel is actually explicitly incompatible with standard CSV, and thus may be incompatible with many othe CSV-supporting programs. You have to make your mind what is your true end goal, to have Excel workbook or to have a bunch of standard CSV files. You also have to learn whether your FBK file is of Firebird 3 versio nor prior. You can try IBExpert Personal or IBExpert Trial, it has Firebird Embedded 2.5 bundled which should be enough for both functions, Restore Database and Extract (restored) Database to work. Not with FB3 though

Answer (score 2):

A `.fbk`-file is - usually - a Firebird gbak backup file, which means it is a binary logical backup of a Firebird database. You first need to [restore](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/firebirddocs/gbak/firebird-gbak.html#gbak-recipies) it, after restore, you can query the tables in the database, and produce CSV from it using any tool that is capable of querying a Firebird database and produce CSV (eg FBExport, and most database query tools, for example DBeaver).

I'm not aware of tools that can directly convert .fbk to CSV files.

Comment: I have never used Firebird. Can you please show me an exaple? Or can you have  atry with my file?

Comment: See [Backup & Restore Recipes](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/firebirddocs/gbak/firebird-gbak.html#gbak-recipies) in the Firebird gbak documentation. You need to have Firebird Server installed. I have no idea what you mean with "Or can you have atry with my file".

Comment: Thank you MArk. I've seen that documentation. 
I installed it. I have the Firebird ISQL Tool available, but I'm not able to restore the fbk file there. 
I'm not an IT and I do not have knowledge about these. 
I tried to use FullConvert software, but still unsuccessful. 

PS" I meant if you could help me. Anyway. Thnx

Comment: @EsHo The ISQL tool is a basic tool for querying a Firebird database. It cannot restore a backup, nor can it export CSV. To restore a backup, you'd use `gbak -r <path-to-fbk-file> <path-to-new-database>`. After restore, you then connect to the newly created database.

Comment: @esho Use FlameRobin, or IBExpert PErsonal, or even fullfeatured but temporary IBExpert Trial. Mark also mentioned FBExport tools, but if you don't even know WHAT is inside the database, then dunno how would you use them. CSV is one table. But database is many tables and many "constraints" (declarative limitations on data consistency driven by business rules) and often also some small programming scripts in PSQL language. You can run IBExpert to enlist all the tables and Extract them one by one into XLSX or DBF or XML or whatever files. But i am not sure if it really would be enough for you.